# C# RichTextBox Environment.NewLine not working.1

Tags: c#, newline, richtextbox

I have a custom class to work as a debug console in a winform app. It is writing everything fine with the exception that it never, ever, goes to the next line (wordwrap is set to false intentionally). This is my class:

```
public static class ConsoleEx
{
    private static RichTextBox outTarget;

    public static void Initialize(RichTextBox target) { outTarget = target; }

    public static void Write( string source, string message ) { Write( source, Color.LightSkyBlue, message );}
    public static void Write( string source, Color sourceColor, string message ) { Write( source, sourceColor, message, Color.Silver );}
    public static void Write( string source, Color sourceColor, string message, Color messageColor )
    {
        if ( outTarget.InvokeRequired )
        {
            outTarget.Invoke( (MethodInvoker)delegate { Write( source, sourceColor, message, messageColor ); } );

            return;
        }

        int wordStart = outTarget.TextLength;

        outTarget.AppendText( source );
        outTarget.Select(wordStart, source.Length);
        outTarget.SelectionColor = sourceColor;

        wordStart = outTarget.TextLength;
        outTarget.DeselectAll();

        outTarget.AppendText( message );
        outTarget.Select(wordStart, source.Length);

        outTarget.SelectionColor = messageColor;
        outTarget.DeselectAll();
    }

    public static void WriteLine( string source, string message ) { Write( source, Color.LightSkyBlue, message);}
    public static void WriteLine( string source, Color sourceColor, string message ) { Write( source, sourceColor, message, Color.Silver );}
    public static void WriteLine( string source, Color sourceColor, string message, Color messageColor )
    {

        if (outTarget.InvokeRequired)
        {
            outTarget.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { WriteLine(source, sourceColor, message, messageColor); });

            return;
        }

        Write( source, sourceColor, message, messageColor );
        outTarget.AppendText( Environment.NewLine );
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have a Write and a WriteLine section. Write will, of course, not append a new line. But when I use WriteLine, it executes and does the last line `outTarget.AppendText( Environment.NewLine );` and, I'm assuming, is appending it as one would expect. But it isn't working. After waiting for about 20 lines to print to the "console" RichTextBox, every single line was just appended to line 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried “\n” after after the message?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did a silly. I accidentally made the two WriteLine chain to Write instead of the third WriteLine. Lol, -facedesk.-